# donot open ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone

i am trying to open ABPersonViewController at table delegate method (DidSelectRowAtIndex). but when i tap on one of my contact person in table view it shows "obj msg send". help me
here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Fetch the address book 
    if ((people != nil) && [people count])
    {   

        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        //ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABPersonViewController" bundle:nil];

        ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
        ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

        personController.addressBook = addressBook;
        personController.personViewDelegate = self;
        personController.displayedPerson = person;
        personController.allowsEditing = YES;       
        //navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init] ;
        [self presentModalViewController:personController animated:YES];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
        [personController release];     
    }   else 
    {
        // Show an alert if "KETAN" is not in Contacts
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                        message:@"Could not find naina in the Contacts application" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    [people release];

}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to get contact person's information?

Comment: @marvin:i need to open ABPersonViewController when i select any name in contactsin editable mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line instead of that in your code,

```
ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABPersonViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an unnecessary release here, `CFRelease(person);`. You are just getting the value directly from an array so you shouldn't release it. Moreover, the `ABPersonViewController` object doesn't retain the `person` object assigned to `displayedPerson` so this results in an error when it tries to access the object which has been released.

Comment: person contain info about contacts..so what should i do?

Comment: when i use presentmodal view controller it shows ABPersonviewcontroller without editing mode. but when i use navigation then it get terminate. i guess my navigation is not working..

Comment: i have run above edited code but still controller is in not editable mode. edit button is not displaying .

Comment: @deepak: why its not opening in edit mode....plz help me!!i have edited the code..navigation bar is missing in ABPersonViewController

Comment: I am really unsure but I have made a [`quick project`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/Addressed.zip) that's working. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the personview to open in edit mode, in addition to `allowsEditing = YES`, you need to specify `setEditing:YES`:

```
[personController setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```